# Comma separated print()

Tags: syntax, lua, null

Hopefully this isn't a dumb question, but I have been searching around after stumbling across this and I cannot find anywhere that this is documented.  What is the use of the comma (`,`) in `print()` statements.  It seems to concatenate with a tab between inputs.

Example:

```
print("this" .. "is" .. "string" .. "concatenation");
print("how", "is", "this", "also", "working?");
```

Output:

```
thisisstringconcatenation 

how is  this    also    working?
```

The reason why I even bother researching this is because it seems to allow concatenation of `nil` values.

Example 2:

```
local nilValues = nil;

print("This", "somehow", "seems", "to", "concatenate", nilValues);
print("This" .. "will" .. "crash" .. "on" .. nilValues); -- ERROR -> attempt to concatenate local 'nilValues' (a nil value)
```

Output 2:

```
This    somehow seems   to  concatenate nil

Error: lua: test.lua:7: attempt to concatenate local 'nilValues' (a nil
value)
```

I've tried searching for the usage of commas in string concatenation and also examined the documents on `print()` from the [Lua guide](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html), but I cannot find anything that explains this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` can take  a variable number of arguments, and insert `\t` between the items printed. You can think that as if `print` is defined like this: (although it actually isn't, this example code is taken from **Programming in Lua** http://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html)

```
printResult = ""

function print (...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    printResult = printResult .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
  printResult = printResult .. "\n"
end
```

In Example 2

```
local nilValues = nil;

print("This", "somehow", "seems", "to", "concatenate", nilValues);
print("This" .. "will" .. "crash" .. "on" .. nilValues);
```

The first `print` takes multiple arguments and prints them all one by one with `\t` in between. Note that `print(nil)` is valid, and will print `nil`.

The second `print` takes a single argument, that is a string. But the string argument `"This" .. "will" .. "crash" .. "on" .. nilValues` is invalid because `nil` can't be concatenated with strings.

Comment: Actually, even PiL 1 has this sample code, it is misleading: print doesn't add a tab character at the end of each line. Replace the loop with this and it works (in Lua 5.1): `printResult = table.concat(arg,"\t")`

Comment: @catwell To be sure, I checked the Lua source code, `print` did add `\t`. See the function `luaB_print`. The Pil1 code is just for reference.

Comment: @YuHao You mean this luaB_print: http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_print? It does not add a terminal `\t`. Here is what your example would look like if it used the same logic as this function: https://gist.github.com/catwell/5704652

Answer (score 2):

```
print("this" .. "is" .. "string" .. "concatenation");
print("how", "is", "this", "also", "working?");
```

In the first print, there is only one parameter. It is a string, "thisisstringconcatenation". Because it does the concatenation first, then pass to the print function.

In the second print, there are 5 parameters to pass to the print.

```
local nilValues = nil;

print("This", "somehow", "seems", "to", "concatenate", nilValues);
print("This" .. "will" .. "crash" .. "on" .. nilValues);
```

In the second example, you concat a string with a nil values.Then cause the error